# Unable to set a tooltip with setData when using QListView with QStringListModel

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using a QListView widget in my application with QStringListModel as the model. Here's the complete code:

`main.cpp`

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

`mainwindow.h`

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

`mainwindow.cpp`

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QStringListModel>
#include <QListView>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setFixedSize(400, 400);

    auto listView = new QListView;
    setCentralWidget(listView);

    auto model = new QStringListModel;
    listView->setModel(model);

    QStringList list;
    list << "item 1" << "item 2";
    model->setStringList(list);
    auto idx = model->index(0);
    model->setData(idx, "Some tooltip", Qt::ToolTipRole);
    model->setData(idx, "actually, item 11", Qt::DisplayRole);
}
```

The result:

[image]

As can be seen, the second `setData` call succeeds and the item text is changed, but the tooltip simply doesn't work; I can hover my mouse as much as I want over the first entry, and nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data structure of `QStringListModel` is a simple list of strings. It handles only `Qt::DisplayRole` and/or `Qt::EditRole`. If you check the return value of `setData()`, you'll see that it returns `false` for `Qt::ToolTipRole`. You might want to switch to a model that can handle multiple roles, such as `QStandardItemModel`.